# Gulp - Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _gallery2.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

gallery.js

```
function initializeGallery() {
    //function stuff
}

export default initializeGallery();
```

main.js

```
import Gallery from './gallery/gallery.js';
```

The above code is causing an error in my local machine but I'm unsure why. I'm using gulp-babel and broswerify to transpile / package everything up

Any help would be appreciate and please let me know if I need to provide any more information

Here is some more code, this is what gets outputted from the gulp task to the browser

```
var _gallery = require('./gallery/gallery.js');

var _gallery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_gallery);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }

(function mainInit() {

    function initializePage() {
        initializePrimaryNavigationDropdown();
        initializeMobileNavButton();
        initializeFooterDropdown();
        initializeIFrame();
        (0, _gallery2.default)();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us more code?

Comment: I've added some more code showing what my code gets transpiled to, hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like they are mistaking the return value of *initializeGallery* as a function that can be invoked.

Comment: @AndrewLi Any ideas what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Well depends. I would do `export default initializeGallery;` then in main, import and execute there. But without more code I wouldn't know much of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewLi You had the answer! Removed the () from my export statement and it worked.